# NoMethodError: undefined method `belong_to' for test when using shoulda-matchers in unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shoulda, shoulda-matchers

I tried to use shoulda-matchers to test the association between models. However, it always show Error:
TakingTest#test_belongs_to:
NoMethodError: undefined method `belong_to' for #<TakingTest:0x00007fc14b8e64a8>
    test/models/taking_test.rb:8:in`block in '
I checked other answer, most of them are at least 4 years ago. Does it still work with rails 6.0?

ruby '2.6.5'

rails', '~> 6.0.2'

gem file

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
group :test do
  gem 'shoulda', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end
```

spec/rails_helper.rb:

```
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
 end
end
```

test/models/taking_test.rb

```
class TakingTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
   test "belongs to" do
     should belong_to(:students)
   end
end
```

Comment: You followed the intructions for integrating Shoulda with RSpec yet thats a Minitest test. Are you trying to write a test or a spec or do you just not know the difference? https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#minitest

Answer (score 0):

Having both a `spec` directory and a `test` directory could be causing your problem. IMO, there should only ever be `spec` or `test` for a every project, never both.

Usually, test files begin with an include for the `test_helper.rb` file.

```
require 'test_helper'
```

Instead of a `test_helper`, you've got a `spec_helper`.

Try moving the Shoulda initializer from `spec/spec_helper.rb` to `test/test_helper.rb`